# How programmatically change IconTintColor of the button if I use a component TStyleBook?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I use Delphi 10.3 Version 26.0.36039.7899. In my Android app to change icon color of the "favorites" button i use this simple trick:

```
procedure TfMain.LinkPropertyToFieldText4AssignedValue(Sender: TObject;
  AssignValueRec: TBindingAssignValueRec; const Value: TValue);
begin
  sbtnFavorites.StyledSettings := sbtnFavorites.StyledSettings - [TStyledSetting.FontColor];
  if Value.AsString = '1' then
    sbtnFavorites.IconTintColor := TAlphaColors.Hotpink;
  if Value.AsString = '0' then
    sbtnFavorites.IconTintColor := TAlphaColorRec.Grey;
end;
```

The sbtnFavorites button has `StyleLookUp = bookmarkstoolbutton` and `StyledSettins.FontColor = False`. It works nice, the button sbtnFavorites changes its color depending on the value of the field "IsFavor" in the local database.

But if I put the component TStyleBook on the form and then assign any style *(f.e. AndroidSterling.style)* to it, then the method I have already described here does not work. The color of the button sbtnFavorites which has StyleLookUp = bookmarkstoolbutton does not change.

And here's my question: how programmatically change the color of the button icon (IconTintColor) if I use a component TStyleBook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chose a much simpler solution to this problem than Chris Pimlott suggested:

1. `sbtnFavorites.StyleLookup := '';`
2. 

```
procedure TfMain.LinkPropertyToFieldHintAssignedValue(Sender: TObject;
  AssignValueRec: TBindingAssignValueRec; const Value: TValue);
begin
  if Value.AsString = '1' then
    sbtnFavorites.ImageIndex := 1;
  if Value.AsString = '0' then
    sbtnFavorites.ImageIndex := 0;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the style file applies to the book. For a style to support tinting it need to implement the correct TintedButton element within the style book itself. It isn’t “automatic” for a particular style (e.g. bookmark) so it sounds like the style file you chose hasn’t implemented the tinted element.

Edit the style book In the designer and take a look at how the styles are build - it’s very enlightening to see how they’re made. It’s surprisingly less “magic” than I first thought!